# Recovering key without factoring

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

The cryptosystem encrypts messages encoded as integers by multiplying them by a constant $k$ (the key).

We have these ciphertexts obtained using this method:
$$27186406060725269473008806173633$$
$$17353206699927246826577369753699$$
How can we find the key to this cipher?

I thought about finding the $\gcd$ of the 2 numbers we have, but I doubt that'd be of much value.

Comment: I think the whole idea of this question is the common primes in the RSA moduli. If you have collected RSA moduli, the first thing you do is [GCD them ALL](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76757/18298)

Answer (score 1):

Finding the $\gcd$ is the way forward. The assumption the question makes is that both ciphertexts were encrypted using the same key, which means multiplication with the same number; the $\gcd$ in this case turns out to be a large *prime*, $398097621494482543747$. The two messages are the integers $68290802539$ and $43590330017$ respectively.

Comment: how did you come up with the messages?

Comment: @cryptoclownclass Get the $\gcd$ of the two numbers in Python. Then run the result through [factordb.com](http://factordb.com) to verify it's a prime. Then divide both by the $\gcd$.